# Class Attributes Not Found Python

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, pycharm, initialization, attributeerror

Here is my code:

[image]

Here is my error:

[image]

I'm very confused why this is happening. I'm using an instance of the class `JinderBot` and the `__init__` function clearly sets the `driver` attribute. Please help point out my mistake.

I'm using PyCharm and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add methods to the class to access and set the attributes.

```
class JinderBot:

    def __init__(self):
         self.atrib = “foobar”

    def _get(self):
         return self.atrib

    def _set(self, atrib)
         self.atrib = atrib 

    bot = JinderBot() 
    print(bot._get())
    bot._set(“updating attribute”)
    print(bot._get())
```

Comment: I typed __int__ instead of __init__. Haha 45 minutes well spent!